# Background color is shown with Mozilla even if visibility is hidden

Tags: html, css

In my CSS, with Mozilla even if I put `visibility: hidden` on a `<td>` tag the background color is shown.

Open this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTTzb/2/). With Chrome it is okay, but with not with Mozilla.

Comment: Do you want to color only the visible cells ?
It's on header and rows or specifically rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Firefox handles this situation properly to my mind. You set background color of `tr` but make invisible `td`. `tr` should still be visible. So it is.

Instead try this CSS:

```
table td,
table th {
    background-color: beige;   
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mTTzb/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: none;` instead if it matches your need. Keep in mind however that contrary to `visibility: hidden;`, the place occupied by your content will be freed for next displayed block.

You can also apply the background style on td and th instead of tr:

```
th,td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

See result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mTTzb/5/

Comment: thnaks @jthe finally `display: none;` works also. but setting `background-color` to `td` and `th` instead of `tr` is the best way to understand .

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `visibility:hidden;` attribute for `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following CSS rule:

```
table tr {
 background-color: beige;   
}
```

The rule states that every row on any table has a background color.
When you set the cell's visibility to hidden, although the cell remains hidden, it's space remains within the row.
That's why you can see color in the space where the cell is.

You can either set the display:none so the cell space isn't used or you can set the background color on the cells instead of rows:

```
table tr td,th {
 background-color: beige;   
}
```